# Apache FTP Path

Tags: php, apache

I have just set up my VPS with Webmin & Kloxo. Kloxo has just created an FTP account for me at: /home/admin/public_html

When I try to access my ftp account it can just access to that specific public_html directory which is the actual problem. I would like to be able to access 1 directory over the public_html, so: /home/admin/

This is because I'd like to place my include files out of the public_html, so people will not be able to access it.

Is it a good idea? If yes, how could I make my FTP account, so it can go 1 directory over the public_html? I guess I should do something with Apache.

Answer (score 0):

ftp has nothing to do with apache. apache only responds to http requests...

I don't know these tools, but the ftp accounts are chrooted (change-rooted). may you can completely disable the chroot jail for ftp using your tools or alternatively set custom chroot paths.

Comment: ftp has nothing to do with apache - unless you are using mod_ftp or mod_proxy_ftp.

Comment: Than sorry. I'M not so experienced with this. Could you please explain me how can I do that? So I can have an FTP account over the public_html?

Comment: I have found that PureFTPd has the function to chroot, but I don't know how. It doesn't tells me how to do it :(

Comment: usually you simply create the file `/etc/pure-ftpd/conf/ChrootEveryone` with the content `yes` and restart the service